# React not importing App.js file correctly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, intellij-idea

Why will my react code not import from App.js.

Anytime i load my localhost it just stays blank.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhLyn.png)

Comment: how do you run your app? Could you share a project you have problems with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent updates of React require it to be layed out in the current syntax:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the root(line: 9), you need to render App Component to see its content ...

```
root.render(
    <App />
 );
```